# Draw item on scene widgetDisplay PyQt6 (camera sight frame)

Tags: python, user-interface, video-streaming, pyside6, pyqt6

I need to display a reticle on top of a video stream.

Now the video stream overlaps the aiming mark and the video scene.

[image: Open]
[image: Run video stream]
[image: I’ll scroll while the video stream is running.]

**mainUI.py**

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'PyUICBasicDemo.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt6 UI code generator 6.6.1
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic6 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(869, 636)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.ComboDevices = QtWidgets.QComboBox(parent=self.centralWidget)
        self.ComboDevices.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 511, 22))
        self.ComboDevices.setObjectName("ComboDevices")
**************************************************************************************
        self.widgetDisplay = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(parent=self.centralWidget)
        self.widgetDisplay.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 511, 401))
        self.widgetDisplay.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.widgetDisplay.setObjectName("widgetDisplay")
***************************************************************************************
        self.gridLayoutWidget_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=self.widgetDisplay)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, -1, 511, 401))
        self.gridLayoutWidget_4.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget_4")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget_4)
        self.gridLayout_3.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.gridLayout_3.setSpacing(6)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.groupInit = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(parent=self.centralWidget)
        self.groupInit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 20, 211, 101))
        self.groupInit.setObjectName("groupInit")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=self.groupInit)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 19, 201, 81))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.bnClose = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.bnClose.setEnabled(False)
        self.bnClose.setObjectName("bnClose")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.bnClose, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.bnOpen = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.bnOpen.setObjectName("bnOpen")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.bnOpen, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.bnEnum = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.bnEnum.setObjectName("bnEnum")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.bnEnum, 1, 1, 1, 2)
        self.groupGrab = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(parent=self.centralWidget)
        self.groupGrab.setEnabled(False)
        self.groupGrab.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 130, 241, 171))
        self.groupGrab.setObjectName("groupGrab")
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=self.groupGrab)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 19, 222, 141))
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget_2")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.gridLayout_2.setSpacing(6)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.bnSaveImage = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.bnSaveImage.setEnabled(False)
        self.bnSaveImage.setObjectName("bnSaveImage")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.bnSaveImage, 4, 0, 1, 2)
        self.radioContinueMode = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.radioContinueMode.setObjectName("radioContinueMode")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioContinueMode, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.radioTriggerMode = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.radioTriggerMode.setObjectName("radioTriggerMode")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioTriggerMode, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.bnStop = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.bnStop.setEnabled(False)
        self.bnStop.setObjectName("bnStop")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.bnStop, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.bnStart = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.bnStart.setEnabled(False)
        self.bnStart.setObjectName("bnStart")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.bnStart, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.bnSoftwareTrigger = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.bnSoftwareTrigger.setEnabled(False)
        self.bnSoftwareTrigger.setObjectName("bnSoftwareTrigger")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.bnSoftwareTrigger, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        self.groupParam = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(parent=self.centralWidget)
        self.groupParam.setEnabled(False)
        self.groupParam.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 310, 211, 151))
        self.groupParam.setObjectName("groupParam")
        self.gridLayoutWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=self.groupParam)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 201, 131))
        self.gridLayoutWidget_3.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget_3")
        self.gridLayoutParam = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget_3)
        self.gridLayoutParam.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.gridLayoutParam.setSpacing(6)
        self.gridLayoutParam.setObjectName("gridLayoutParam")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget_3)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.gridLayoutParam.addWidget(self.label_6, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.edtGain = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget_3)
        self.edtGain.setObjectName("edtGain")
        self.gridLayoutParam.addWidget(self.edtGain, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget_3)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.gridLayoutParam.addWidget(self.label_5, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget_3)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayoutParam.addWidget(self.label_4, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.edtExposureTime = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget_3)
        self.edtExposureTime.setObjectName("edtExposureTime")
        self.gridLayoutParam.addWidget(self.edtExposureTime, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.bnGetParam = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget_3)
        self.bnGetParam.setObjectName("bnGetParam")
        self.gridLayoutParam.addWidget(self.bnGetParam, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.bnSetParam = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget_3)
        self.bnSetParam.setObjectName("bnSetParam")
        self.gridLayoutParam.addWidget(self.bnSetParam, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.edtFrameRate = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget_3)
        self.edtFrameRate.setObjectName("edtFrameRate")
        self.gridLayoutParam.addWidget(self.edtFrameRate, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayoutParam.setColumnStretch(0, 2)
        self.gridLayoutParam.setColumnStretch(1, 3)
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(parent=self.centralWidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 470, 211, 71))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.bnStart_focus = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.groupBox)
        self.bnStart_focus.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 75, 24))
        self.bnStart_focus.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CursorShape.ArrowCursor))
        self.bnStart_focus.setObjectName("bnStart_focus")
        self.bntest = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.groupBox)
        self.bntest.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 30, 97, 24))
        self.bntest.setObjectName("bntest")
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(parent=self.centralWidget)
        self.groupBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 500, 120, 80))
        self.groupBox_2.setWhatsThis("")
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.lcdNumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(parent=self.groupBox_2)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 101, 41))
        self.lcdNumber.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CursorShape.ArrowCursor))
        self.lcdNumber.setWhatsThis("")
        self.lcdNumber.setAccessibleName("")
        self.lcdNumber.setAccessibleDescription("")
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName("lcdNumber")
        self.widgetDisplay.raise_()
        self.ComboDevices.raise_()
        self.groupInit.raise_()
        self.groupGrab.raise_()
        self.groupParam.raise_()
        self.groupBox.raise_()
        self.groupBox_2.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.groupInit.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Initialization"))
        self.bnClose.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close Device"))
        self.bnOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open Device"))
        self.bnEnum.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Find Devices"))
        self.groupGrab.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Acquisition"))
        self.bnSaveImage.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save Image"))
        self.radioContinueMode.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Continuous Mode"))
        self.radioTriggerMode.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Trigger Mode"))
        self.bnStop.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop Acquisition"))
        self.bnStart.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start Acquisition"))
        self.bnSoftwareTrigger.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Software Trigger Once"))
        self.groupParam.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Parameters"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Frame Rate"))
        self.edtGain.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Gain"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exposure"))
        self.edtExposureTime.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.bnGetParam.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Get Parameters"))
        self.bnSetParam.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Set Parameters"))
        self.edtFrameRate.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Автофокус"))
        self.bnStart_focus.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.bntest.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Резкость"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**mainwindow.py**

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, QtMultimediaWidgets
from PyQt6.QtCore import QThreadPool, Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox
from PyQt6.QtGui import QBrush, QPen, QColor
from Camera_net.BasicDemo.CamOperation_class import CameraOperation
from Camera_net.MvImport.MvCameraControl_class import *
from Camera_net.MvImport.MvErrorDefine_const import *
from Camera_net.MvImport.CameraParams_header import *
from GUI.thread_process_worker import RobotClientWorker
from GUI.mainUI import Ui_MainWindow

class CameraApplication(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.deviceList = MV_CC_DEVICE_INFO_LIST()
        self.cam = MvCamera()
        self.nSelCamIndex = 0
        self.obj_cam_operation = None
        self.isOpen = False
        self.isGrabbing = False

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.ui.bnEnum.clicked.connect(self.enum_devices)
        self.ui.bnOpen.clicked.connect(self.open_device)
        self.ui.bnClose.clicked.connect(self.close_device)
        self.ui.bnStart.clicked.connect(self.start_grabbing)
        self.ui.bnStop.clicked.connect(self.stop_grabbing)
        self.ui.bnSoftwareTrigger.clicked.connect(self.trigger_once)
        self.ui.radioTriggerMode.clicked.connect(self.set_software_trigger_mode)
        self.ui.radioContinueMode.clicked.connect(self.set_continue_mode)
        self.ui.bnGetParam.clicked.connect(self.get_param)
        self.ui.bnSetParam.clicked.connect(self.set_param)
        self.ui.bnSaveImage.clicked.connect(self.save_bmp)
        self.ui.bnStart_focus.clicked.connect(self.start_focus)
        self.ui.bntest.clicked.connect(lambda: (None, None))
***************************************************************************************
        # Create a QGraphicsScene and set it as the scene for the display widget
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.ui.widgetDisplay.setScene(self._scene)

        # Create a video item and add it to the scene
        self._videoitem = QtMultimediaWidgets.QGraphicsVideoItem()
        self._videoitem.setSize(QtCore.QSizeF(500, 400))

        # Define a rectangle for the ellipse
        self._circle_item_rect = QtCore.QRectF(-20, -20, 40, 40)

        # Create an ellipse and add it to the scene (should be added after the video item)
        self._circle_item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem(self._circle_item_rect, parent=None)
        self._circle_item.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(0, 0, 255)))
        self._circle_item.setPen(QPen(QColor(255, 0, 0)))

        # Set the position of the ellipse
        self._circle_item.setPos(100, 100)

        # Stack the ellipse behind the video item
        self._circle_item.stackBefore(self._videoitem)

        # Set the Z-values to control the layering of items
        self._videoitem.setZValue(0)
        self._circle_item.setZValue(1)

        # Add items to the scene
        self._scene.addItem(self._videoitem)
        self._scene.addItem(self._circle_item)

        # Make the ellipse the active panel
        self._scene.setActivePanel(self._circle_item)
*********************************************************************
    def TxtWrapBy(self, start_str, end, all):
        start = all.find(start_str)
        if start >= 0:
            start += len(start_str)
            end = all.find(end, start)
            if end >= 0:
                return all[start:end].strip()

    # Converts the returned error code to hexadecimal display
    def ToHexStr(self, num):
        chaDic = {10: 'a', 11: 'b', 12: 'c', 13: 'd', 14: 'e', 15: 'f'}
        hexStr = ""
        if num < 0:
            num = num + 2 ** 32
        while num >= 16:
            digit = num % 16
            hexStr = chaDic.get(digit, str(digit)) + hexStr
            num //= 16
        hexStr = chaDic.get(num, str(num)) + hexStr
        return hexStr

    def enum_devices(self):
        self.deviceList = MV_CC_DEVICE_INFO_LIST()
        ret = MvCamera.MV_CC_EnumDevices(MV_GIGE_DEVICE | MV_USB_DEVICE, self.deviceList)
        if ret != 0:
            strError = "Enum devices fail! ret = :" + ToHexStr(ret)
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", strError, QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok)
            return ret

        if self.deviceList.nDeviceNum == 0:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Info", "Find no device", QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok)
            return ret

        print("Find %d devices!" % self.deviceList.nDeviceNum)

        devList = []
        for i in range(0, self.deviceList.nDeviceNum):
            mvcc_dev_info = cast(self.deviceList.pDeviceInfo[i], POINTER(MV_CC_DEVICE_INFO)).contents
            if mvcc_dev_info.nTLayerType == MV_GIGE_DEVICE:
                print("\ngige device: [%d]" % i)
                chUserDefinedName = ""
                for per in mvcc_dev_info.SpecialInfo.stGigEInfo.chUserDefinedName:
                    if 0 == per:
                        break
                    chUserDefinedName = chUserDefinedName + chr(per)
                print("device user define name: %s" % chUserDefinedName)

                chModelName = ""
                for per in mvcc_dev_info.SpecialInfo.stGigEInfo.chModelName:
                    if 0 == per:
                        break
                    chModelName = chModelName + chr(per)

                print("device model name: %s" % chModelName)

                nip1 = ((mvcc_dev_info.SpecialInfo.stGigEInfo.nCurrentIp & 0xff000000) >> 24)
                nip2 = ((mvcc_dev_info.SpecialInfo.stGigEInfo.nCurrentIp & 0x00ff0000) >> 16)
                nip3 = ((mvcc_dev_info.SpecialInfo.stGigEInfo.nCurrentIp & 0x0000ff00) >> 8)
                nip4 = (mvcc_dev_info.SpecialInfo.stGigEInfo.nCurrentIp & 0x000000ff)
                print("current ip: %d.%d.%d.%d\n" % (nip1, nip2, nip3, nip4))
                devList.append(
                    "[" + str(i) + "]GigE: " + chUserDefinedName + " " + chModelName + "(" + str(nip1) + "." + str(
                        nip2) + "." + str(nip3) + "." + str(nip4) + ")")
            elif mvcc_dev_info.nTLayerType == MV_USB_DEVICE:
                print("\nu3v device: [%d]" % i)
                chUserDefinedName = ""
                for per in mvcc_dev_info.SpecialInfo.stUsb3VInfo.chUserDefinedName:
                    if per == 0:
                        break
                    chUserDefinedName = chUserDefinedName + chr(per)
                print("device user define name: %s" % chUserDefinedName)

                chModelName = ""
                for per in mvcc_dev_info.SpecialInfo.stUsb3VInfo.chModelName:
                    if 0 == per:
                        break
                    chModelName = chModelName + chr(per)
                print("device model name: %s" % chModelName)

                strSerialNumber = ""
                for per in mvcc_dev_info.SpecialInfo.stUsb3VInfo.chSerialNumber:
                    if per == 0:
                        break
                    strSerialNumber = strSerialNumber + chr(per)
                print("user serial number: %s" % strSerialNumber)
                devList.append("[" + str(i) + "]USB: " + chUserDefinedName + " " + chModelName
                               + "(" + str(strSerialNumber) + ")")

        self.ui.ComboDevices.clear()
        self.ui.ComboDevices.addItems(devList)
        self.ui.ComboDevices.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def open_device(self):
        if self.isOpen:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", 'Camera is Running!', QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok)

            return MV_E_CALLORDER


        self.nSelCamIndex = self.ui.ComboDevices.currentIndex()
        if self.nSelCamIndex < 0:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", 'Please select a camera!', QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok)
            return MV_E_CALLORDER

        self.obj_cam_operation = CameraOperation(self.cam, self.deviceList, self.nSelCamIndex)
        ret = self.obj_cam_operation.Open_device()

        if 0 != ret:
            strError = "Open device failed ret:" + ToHexStr(ret)
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", strError, QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok)
            self.isOpen = False
        else:
            self.set_continue_mode()
            self.get_param()
            self.isOpen = True
            self.enable_controls()

    def update_sharpness_lcd(self, sharpness):
        print(sharpness)
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(sharpness)

    def start_grabbing(self):
        ret = self.obj_cam_operation.Start_grabbing(self.ui.widgetDisplay.winId())
        self.obj_cam_operation.sharpness_signal.connect(self.update_sharpness_lcd)

        if ret != 0:
            strError = "Start grabbing failed ret:" + ToHexStr(ret)
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", strError, QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok)
        else:
            self.isGrabbing = True
            self.enable_controls()



    def stop_grabbing(self):
        ret = self.obj_cam_operation.Stop_grabbing()
        if ret != 0:
            strError = "Stop grabbing failed ret:" + ToHexStr(ret)
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", strError, QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok)
        else:
            self.isGrabbing = False
            self.enable_controls()

    def close_device(self):
        if self.isOpen:
            self.obj_cam_operation.Close_device()
            self.isOpen = False

        self.isGrabbing = False
        self.enable_controls()

    def set_continue_mode(self):
        ret = self.obj_cam_operation.Set_trigger_mode(False)
        if ret != 0:
            strError = "Set continue mode failed ret:" + ToHexStr(ret)
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", strError, QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok)
        else:
            self.ui.radioContinueMode.setChecked(True)
            self.ui.radioTriggerMode.setChecked(False)
            self.ui.bnSoftwareTrigger.setEnabled(False)

    def set_software_trigger_mode(self):
        ret = self.obj_cam_operation.Set_trigger_mode(True)
        if ret != 0:
            strError = "Set trigger mode failed ret:" + ToHexStr(ret)
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", strError, QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok)
        else:
            self.ui.radioContinueMode.setChecked(False)
            self.ui.radioTriggerMode.setChecked(True)
            self.ui.bnSoftwareTrigger.setEnabled(self.isGrabbing)

    def trigger_once(self):
        ret = self.obj_cam_operation.Trigger_once()
        if ret != 0:
            strError = "TriggerSoftware failed ret:" + ToHexStr(ret)
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", strError, QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok)

    def save_bmp(self):
        ret = self.obj_cam_operation.Save_Bmp()
        if ret != MV_OK:
            strError = "Save BMP failed ret:" + ToHexStr(ret)
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", strError, QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok)
        else:
            print("Save image success")

    def get_param(self):
        ret = self.obj_cam_operation.Get_parameter()
        if ret != MV_OK:
            strError = "Get param failed ret:" + ToHexStr(ret)
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", strError, QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok)
        else:
            self.ui.edtExposureTime.setText("{0:.2f}".format(self.obj_cam_operation.exposure_time))
            self.ui.edtGain.setText("{0:.2f}".format(self.obj_cam_operation.gain))
            self.ui.edtFrameRate.setText("{0:.2f}".format(self.obj_cam_operation.frame_rate))

    def set_param(self):
        frame_rate = self.ui.edtFrameRate.text()
        exposure = self.ui.edtExposureTime.text()
        gain = self.ui.edtGain.text()
        ret = self.obj_cam_operation.Set_parameter(frame_rate, exposure, gain)
        if ret != MV_OK:
            strError = "Set param failed ret:" + ToHexStr(ret)
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", strError, QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok)

        return MV_OK

    def start_focus(self):
        robot_client_worker = RobotClientWorker(self.obj_cam_operation)
        thread_pool = QThreadPool.globalInstance()
        thread_pool.start(robot_client_worker)


    def enable_controls(self):
        self.ui.groupGrab.setEnabled(self.isOpen)
        self.ui.groupParam.setEnabled(self.isOpen)

        self.ui.bnOpen.setEnabled(not self.isOpen)
        self.ui.bnClose.setEnabled(self.isOpen)

        self.ui.bnStart.setEnabled(self.isOpen and (not self.isGrabbing))
        self.ui.bnStop.setEnabled(self.isOpen and self.isGrabbing)
        self.ui.bnSoftwareTrigger.setEnabled(self.isGrabbing and self.ui.radioTriggerMode.isChecked())

        self.ui.bnSaveImage.setEnabled(self.isOpen and self.isGrabbing)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = CameraApplication()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

1. Trying change layering num
2. Change position items on the scene
3. Delete self.widgetDisplay.raise_() and write self.*circle_item.raise*()
4. self._circle_item.stackBefore(self._videoitem)
5. self._scene.setActivePanel(self._circle_item)

> I assume there is some kind of structural error in my code.

**It is necessary to either somehow draw a circle on top of the video or display the video correctly in the scene.**

Comment: You cannot embed video like this and then draw *above* so easily, most importantly because video playback can even be a hardware overlay that's completely outside of the program scope. Consider using the QtMultimedia module. Note that your code is very extended, while we generally need a [mre] (emphasis on *minimal*). Also, on top of the pyuic generated file there's a clear warning about **not** editing such files unless you know what you're doing (which is the case, since some of the modifications you did there are inappropriate), so please don't do it. Your layout management also has issues.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll redo the project